# Upgrade Pandas with version 1.4.4 using pip

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

I am new to python and need your inputs. may be the question is basic.

I have python version : 3.6.5 installed contains pandas version : 0.23.0

I wanted to upgrade Pandas verion with 1.4.4 on the same python version.

Could you please help me how we can upgrade. do i need to cehck any dependencies before upgrade.

Thanks

I am new to python and need your inputs.

Comment: in the pandas DOC 1.4.4 is compatible with Python 3.8, 3.9 and 3.10. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.4.4/getting_started/install.html